# proving this linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T : V → V$ be a linear map, where $dim(V ) = n$, and suppose that $T^n = 0$
and that there exists a vector $v ∈ V$ with $T^{n−1}
(v) \neq 0_V$ . Prove that the vectors
$v, T(v), T^2
(v), . . . , T^{n−1}(v)$ are linearly independent and that the nullity of $T$ is $1$.

I'm not sure whether to approach this by contradiction or induction. Do we need anything other than basic properties of L.I and linear transformations to work this out? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_0v+a_1Tv+\cdots+c_{n-1}T^{n-1} v=0$, Apply $T^{n-1}$ to both sides to see that $a_0=0$. So we get $a_1Tv+\cdots+c_{n-1}T^{n-1} v=0$ and applying $T^{n-2}$ we get $a_1=0$ and so on. This proves that $v,TV,...,T^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent. Since $dim (V)=n$ it follows that this set is actually a basis for $V$.

Now let $x \in Ker(T)$. Write $x$ as $a_0v+a_1Tv+\cdots+c_{n-1}T^{n-1} v$. Apply $T$ to see that $a_0Tv+a_1T^{2}v+\cdots+c_{n-2}T^{n-1}v =0$. By indepedence this implies that $a_0=a_1=..=a_{n-2}=0$ Hence $x=c_{n-1}T^{n-1} v$. We have proved that every vector in the kernel of $T$ is a scalar multiple  of $T^{n-1} v$. [This vector is a non-zero element in the kernel]. Hence the nullity of $T$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that$$\alpha_0v+\alpha_1Tv+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}T^{n-1}v=0.\tag1$$Then$$T^{n-1}(\alpha_0v+\alpha_1Tv+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}T^{n-1}v)=0,$$which means that $\alpha_0T^{n-1}v=0$. Therefore, $\alpha_0=0$. But then $(1)$ means that$$\alpha_1Tv+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}T^{n-1}v=0$$ and you can start all over again (with $T^{n-2}$ instead of $T^{n-1}$).

So, your vectors are linearly independent. Since you have $n$ vectors and $n=\dim V$, they form a basis. And the matrix of $T$ with respect to that basis is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\1&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\0&1&0&\ldots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$And should be cleart now that the nullity of $T$ is indeed $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Induction can work here fine: suppose $\;a_0,...,a_{n-1}\;$ are scalars such that (with $\;T^0=I$)

$$0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kT^kv\stackrel{\text{apply}\;T}\implies0=T0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kT^{k+1}v\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;T^nv=0$$

so we're left only with

$$0=a_0Tv+a_1T^2v+\ldots a_{n-2}T^{n-1}v$$

Now apply again $\;T\;$ on both sides...*and continue inductively*. And etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation:
$$\lambda_0v+\lambda_1Tv+\cdots+\lambda_{n-1}T^{n-1}v = 0$$
for $v$ such that $T^{n-1}(v) \neq 0$. Apply $T^{n-1}$ on this equation. It will give you $\lambda_0 = 0$. Now apply $T^{n-2}$ on the rest of the equation. What does that give you? You should be able to write out the rest of this argument.